# Problem on using appendChild or innerHtml

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml, dom-manipulation

I want to append my `tr` and `td` into `tbody` by using javascript not jQuery. Currently I am using jquery .html() I want to change it with Javascript.

```
var arrStrData = [];

for (i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
    arrStrData.push("<tr>");
    arrStrData.push("<td>");
    arrStrData.push(objData[i].FirstName);
    arrStrData.push("</td>");
    arrStrData.push("<td>");
    arrStrData.push(objData[i].LastName);
    arrStrData.push("</td>");
    arrStrData.push("<td>");
    arrStrData.push(objData[i].Gender);
    arrStrData.push("</td>");
    arrStrData.push("<td>");
    arrStrData.push(objData[i].Country);
    arrStrData.push("</td>");
    arrStrData.push("<td>");
    arrStrData.push(objData[i].Password);
    arrStrData.push("</td>");
    arrStrData.push("</tr>");
}
$("tbody").html(arrStrData.join(''));
```

Comment: where is the table whats the id. please show more code

Comment: If your already using jQuery how come you don't want jQuery to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minimal change to your current code, you can follow it with:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<table><tbody>' + arrStrData.join('') + '</tbody></table>';
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(
  div.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0], tbody
);
```

A more general version might be:

```
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var oRow = document.createElement('tr');
var oCell = document.createElement('td');
var propArray = ['FirstName','LastName','Gender',
                 'Country','Password'];
var row, cell, obj;

for (var i=0, iLen=objData.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  row = oRow.cloneNode(false);
  o = objData[i]

  for (var j=0, jLen=propArray.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    cell = oCell.cloneNode(false);
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o[propArray[j]]));
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  frag.appendChild(row);
}

tbody.appendChild(frag);
```

The above are general approaches that you can adapt to your circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Will only work if there is only one `tbody` element (just as your jQuery example).

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=arrStrData.join('');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/etH6T/)

You'd be better of defining an `id` on your `table` or `tbody` and using `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Do not use innerHTML to modify a table, it will fail in lots of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following URL on implementing addRow in a table using native javascript.

> http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddrow.html

Answer (score 0):

As your already using jQuery why not *use it* to help you, that's what it's there for afterall.

```
var useKeys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Gender', 'Country', 'Password'],
    html = '';

for (var i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
    var row = $(useKeys).map(function(value, key) {
        var value = objData[i][key];
        return '<td>' + (value == undefined ? '' : value) + '</td>';
    }).get();

    html += '<tr>' + row + '</tr>';
}

$('tbody').html(html);
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/dD5tc/)